# Hashing a password for unix shadow file

Tags: hash, hex, md5, shadow

So, I have this entry in a linux shadow file

```
google.:$1$8KdNUQ4R$ZYyUXVGhvLgVNpfqus.GX/::1:0:1:1:::
```

The password for this user is `com`

As I understand the `$1$` means it is hashed using md5;
`8KdNUQ4R` is the salt; and `ZYyUXVGhvLgVNpfqus.GX/` is the hashed password itself.

What confuses me is that md5 generators I found online produce a hex value that is 32 characters long, but the hashed password in this case is only 22 chars long, and definitely not a hex.

What steps do I have to go through to get from `com` to `ZYyUXVGhvLgVNpfqus.GX/` using the given salt ?

**Edit**

So, I found my answer. My problem was that I should have used md5crypt instead of md5.

Comment: usually it's not that simple, you need to look at what your distro is exactly using. This question may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/88284/how-is-a-password-hash-encoded-in-the-shadow-password-file

Comment: The problem is I received only the shadow file as part of an assignment to find as many of the passwords as we can. I thought of hashing words from a word-list and comparing them. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: there seem to be a lot of tools for cracking shadow files especially md5 based. Unlikely to write something faster than what already is available in a reasonable time frame. No personal experience.. but sounds like a waste of time

Comment: I found a tool named John the Ripper that seems to work pretty good, but it's just not that satisfying. I want to know how it works rather than just have the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to calculate hash for particular password use crypt(3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   std::cout << crypt( "com", "$1$8KdNUQ4R" ) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

If you want to know how to get it - result of md5 hash of salt + password is converted to string by base64.

```
slava@bird:~$ g++ crypt.cpp -lcrypt -o crypt_com
slava@bird:~$ ./crypt_com 
$1$8KdNUQ4R$ZYyUXVGhvLgVNpfqus.GX/
```